# TCPL 5.9.9 (C++): Where would it make sense to use a name in its own initializer?

Tags: c++, initializer

This is a question from the most recent version of Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language".

I've been mulling this over in my head for the past couple days.

The only thing I can come up with, (and this is probably incorrect) is something like this:

```
int* f(int n) {
  int* a = &a - n * sizeof(int*);
  return a;
}
```

My intent is to get the address of something higher up on the stack.  Does this make any sense?  Does anyone else have any other answers?  Remember, this is in Chapter 5 (pointers, arrays, and structures) so the answer shouldn't involve something later on in the book.

Comment: What makes you think it should *ever* make sense? :p

Comment: Well, as a portable code, yours is U.B. I guess it means that it doesn't make sense :)

Comment: To be more specific: "stack" is an implementation detail; there isn't such a thing in C++ standard. It only has "automatic storage", without specifying how it's implemented. Furthermore, pointer arithmetic that results in pointer to first element of an array (single variable can be treated as 1-element array for this purpose) decremented is U.B.

Comment: I wonder whether you are allowed to use malloc, too?

Comment: Jalf, I don't think Stroustrup would have asked the question in his book if he didn't think there would be *some* answer to it.

Comment: @RobKennedy: I sometimes wonder what he was trying to answer by inventing C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only (barely) reasonable case I know of is when you want to pass a pointer to the object itself to its constructor. For example, say you have a cyclic linked list node:

```
class Node
{
public:
    Node(Node* next): next(next) {}
private:
    Node* next;
};
```

and you want to create a single-element cyclic list on the stack. You can do this:

```
Node n(&n);
```

A few other examples that aren't really practical (i.e. I don't see why you'd need that sort of thing), but otherwise valid:

```
int n = sizeof(n);
void* p = &p;
```

Comment: "Node(Node* next): next(next) {}" line is very subtle, i like that solution :)

Comment: Although slightly reminiscent of the "spam" sketch :-)

Comment: The first example doesn't seem right to me. `next` and `next` in that ctor-initialiser are not the same name; they each refer to distinct objects.

Comment: The point of the first example is not about the ctor-initializer, it's about declaring the variable `n`. Two names in the initializer are different, yes, but it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

An example I use very often in C code is:

```
C *c = (C*) malloc(sizeof *c);
...
free(c);
```

It involves pointers and structures. Surely, `new` frees you from having to use that idiom by saying `new C` instead in C++.

Comment: Makes most sense of everything posted here so far!

Comment: No, because if you change the type of `c`, you'll need to change it in two places, and might accidentially miss the one inside `sizeof` (and it won't be a compile-time error). This way you only have to change type in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a correct way. Just you need to take care of many things :)

First, you don't need **sizeof** because n will be multiplied by the size of **a**. Basically you have to choose the right type of the pointer to get the address you want on the stack.

```
int*  a = &a - n; // so if n==1 => a = &a - (1*4)
char* b = &b - n; // so if n==1 => b = &b - (1*1)
```

Second, you have to take care of endianess.

Also, I am not sure if I forgot something :)

Comment: you forgot one thing: It's undefined behavior. You're not allowed to do pointer arithmetics beyond the bounds of the original array (where non-array types are considered arrays of a single element) :)

Comment: well thats true, I agree with you it is useful only for a learner and useless after that :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, there is no guarantee about which direction the stack grows. Your code assumes it grows down, but it could also grow up (that is, to lower addresses). Also, there are things that get put on the stack that you may not be aware of (return address, stack frame, registers, etc.) and not "jumping" past when trying to grab things higher up on the stack.

What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to find a reason for using a name in its own initializer.  The example I gave was an attempt at such.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an array of integral type that should hold its size in the first element:

```
// clang++ --std=c++11 initializer.cpp -o initializer

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Print(int* array) {
    cout << "array has " << *array << " elements" << endl;
    for(int count {*array}; count; --count) {
        cout << *++array << endl;
    }
}

int main(int, char* []) {
    {
        int elements[] {sizeof(*elements), 1, 2, 3};
        *elements = sizeof(elements) / *elements - 1;
        Print(elements);
    }
    cout << "---" << endl;
    {
        int elements[] {sizeof(*elements)};
        *elements = sizeof(elements) / *elements - 1;
        Print(elements);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./initializer                                                                                                                                                                                                     
array has 3 elements
1
2
3
---
array has 0 elements
```

P.S. Example in GitHub: [Chapter 8: Exercise 9.3](https://github.com/ksamdev/cpp11/blob/master/chapter8/exercises/x.9.3/initializer.cpp)